# Multiple mappings for a physical page

Tags: c, linux, mmap, virtual-memory

I want to create a copy-on-write like interface for accessing a `mmap()`ed file in GNU C. Here is the way it should work:

1. I will map the file to the address space using `mmap()`. Doing so, I will have a pointer to a contiguous region of memory which will contain real data.
2. Using some sort of magic, I will have another part of the address space pointing to the exact same physical pages. In other words, I will have two different addresses to access any physical page on memory for the `mmap()`ed region.
3. Once an instruction tries to write to a page using the second mapping, I will change the mapping for that particular page to point to a different physical page (which I will create in a on-demand fashion).
4. At some point, I will sync the dirty-page with originally mapped page and change the alias to point to the memory-mapped page.

Here is the question: What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You lost me on point 4. Why is syncing happening? If it is COW then the dirty-page is supposed to be an independent copy. Don't get what and why you are syncing. Also, mmap already has the MAP_PRIVATE option which does COW. How is your requirement different to that?

Comment: The goal is to copy the page on write and apply the changes to the original copy later in order to provide crash consistency. You can think about it as some sort of redo-logging for modified pages of the memory-mapped file. Because of that, I don't want the transparency that MAP_PRIVATE provides and need to be able to change the mapping and do the copy manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not entirely clear on your exact requirements. But here are some options I see.

Let mmap handle the COW for you using MAP_PRIVATE. Then when you are ready to sync just create a regular mmap (or direct file open) to the original file and do your sync with the modified MAP_PRIVATE page.

That doesn't allow you to know whether the MAP_PRIVATE page was actually modified or not. If you want that (e.g. so that you can optimise and not do a sync unless a page has changed) then you can make the MAP_PRIVATE page readonly. On first access a SEGV will occur. Catch that SEGV with a signal handler and re-map the MAP_PRIVATE page to be writeable and internally note it as dirty.

And finally, if you don't want to use MAP_PRIVATE and want full copy control, just don't use MMAP_PRIVATE but do a readonly mapping and signal handler. In the signal handler, allocate some memory, copy the original page and remap the faulting page.

Hope that all makes sense.